# Control output when split a large text file in pieces

Tags: linux, split, large-files

I would need your help about how can I control the output when I split a large text file in pieces.

For exemple, in this moment when I run the command

```
split -l 2000 file newfile-
```

The current output is

```
newfile-aa
newfile-ab
etc
```

What I would like to have, if is possible

```
newfile-000
newfile-001
newfile-002
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
split -l 2000 -a 3 -d file newfile-
```

The -a 3 sets the suffix to 3 characters.

The -d uses numeric suffixes.

Comment: I've tried with, but it doesn't work... split: invalid option -- 'c'